# Why doesn't `putStrLn getLine` work?

Tags: haskell, stdio

I'm complete newbie on Haskell.
My Haskell script with `GHCi`,

```
Prelude> let a = putStrLn getLine
```

makes an error like this.

```
<interactive>:1:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `String'
           against inferred type `IO String'
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `getLine'
    In the expression: putStrLn getLine
    In the definition of `a': a = putStrLn getLine
Prelude>
```

**Why** doesn't it work and how can I print something input from `stdin`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
getLine :: IO String
```

The types do not match.  `getLine` is an `IO` action, and `putStrLn` takes a plain string.

What you need to do is bind the line inside the `IO` monad in order to pass it to `putStrLn`.  The following are equivalent:

```
a = do line <- getLine
       putStrLn line

a = getLine >>= \line -> putStrLn line

a = getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: You've got a value stuck in the IO monad `m a`, and a function that returns its value in the IO monad `a -> m b`. You want to end up with an IO action `m b`. All together that's `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. [Stop. Hoogle time.](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+m+b)+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+mb) `>>=` is one of the first results. :)

Comment: Unfortunately there are no results for the exact instantiation we need: `IO String -> (String -> IO ()) -> IO ()`.

Comment: Eonil it would be closer to the intention of your `putStrLn getLine` to use something like the reversed bind:  `putStrLn =<< getLine`.   This is `fmap` followed by `join`, so we could write `join (putStrLn <$> getLine)`. I wish there were something lovelier than `(=<<)`